# Netbeans: how to create an executable .jar file with all libraries and source files included

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar, netbeans-8

I'm creating a jar file with all the libraries included but I don't know how to include the source code inside the jar.

Is it possible to include the source files in the jar file?

To create the jar file I am using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 and in the build.xml file I have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="SendMail" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project SendMail.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">

        <!-- Change the value of this property to be the
name of your JAR, minus the .jar extension. It should not 
have spaces.
             <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>
        -->

        <property name="store.jar.name" value="SendMail"/>

        <!-- don't edit below this line -->

        <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
        <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

        <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

        <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

        <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
            <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
           
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>

        <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
            <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
            excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
        </zip>

        <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>

    </target>
</project>
```

Then I run the following option

[Target "package-for-store"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSJy4.png)

Right click on the build.xml file, select “Run Target-> Other Targets-> package-for-store”

Once you have run the "package-for-store" target you will notice that a "Store" folder has been created in your project.

It is in this folder you will find the Jar file, it already contains internally the libraries that your program needs so that you can distribute it just by copying this file

It is possible to add the files with the source code in the jar file,
what should be changed in the build.xml

Comment: Use maven's fat jar option

Comment: This [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+netbeans+ant+fat+jar&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active) might provide a bit more insight

Comment: Yes, you can edit **build.xml** to include source files. Take a look at [the Ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) for the `<zipfileset>` tag, which you are already using in your **build.xml**. Studying the example in the linked documentation should point you in the right direction. Update your question to clarify your problem if you are still stuck.